# discord.py. Я хотел сделать бота отправляющего сообщение в определённый канал с id из базы данных. Однако мне выводит ошибку ниже:

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, discord, discord.py

Вот сама ошибка:discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Использую базу MongoDB

```
@client.command()
async def bump(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    chanid = collection.find_one()["chan"]
    text = collection.find_one()["descript"]    
    baner = collection.find_one()["banner"]
    channl = client.get_channel(chanid)
    invite = await ctx.channel.create_invite()
    yes = discord.Embed(
        title = 'Успешная рассылка.',
        description = 'Ваше объявление рассылается по партнёрским серверам, ожидайте.',
        color = 0x00ccd4
    )
    await ctx.send(embed=yes)
    for guild in client.guilds:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = f'{ctx.guild.name}',
            description = f'{text}\n** | Ccылка на сервер**\n**✅ | [Присоединиться]({invite})**\n\n** | Владелец сервера:** {ctx.guild.owner}\n** | Количество участников:** {ctx.guild.member_count}\n`ID: {ctx.guild.id}`',
            color = 0x00ccd4
        )
        embed.set_image(url=baner)
        for channel in guild.channels:
            await channl.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: В какой именно строке ошибка? Вы уверены, что боту точно удается получить объект канала в строке `channl = client.get_channel(chanid)`?

Comment: Я в команде которая указывала chanid превращал аргумент str в числовой(это id сервера). Я проверял базу данных и там числовое значение.

Comment: Ошибка происходит в самой последней строке(вроде)

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно указать ID канала как INT.
Ошибка гласит, то что бот не смог найти канал и отправить в него сообщение.

```py
@client.command()
async def bump(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    chanid = collection.find_one()["chan"]
    text = collection.find_one()["descript"]    
    baner = collection.find_one()["banner"]
    channl = client.get_channel(int(chanid)) # Получаем ID канала как int
    invite = await ctx.channel.create_invite()
    yes = discord.Embed(
        title = 'Успешная рассылка.',
        description = 'Ваше объявление рассылается по партнёрским серверам, ожидайте.',
        color = 0x00ccd4
    )
    await ctx.send(embed=yes)
    for guild in client.guilds:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = f'{ctx.guild.name}',
            description = f'{text}\n** | Ccылка на сервер**\n**✅ | [Присоединиться]({invite})**\n\n** | Владелец сервера:** {ctx.guild.owner}\n** | Количество участников:** {ctx.guild.member_count}\n`ID: {ctx.guild.id}`',
            color = 0x00ccd4
        )
        embed.set_image(url=baner)
        for channel in guild.channels:
            await channl.send(embed=embed)
```